# Resteasy dto null on server

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a following structure:

`AckInfoDto` wrapper for AckDto and PersonDto

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AckInfoDto implements Serializable{


private AckDto ackDto;

private PersonDto personDto;

public AckInfoDto() {
}

...getters/setters...
}
```

`AckDto`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AckDto extends BaseDto {

...fields...
public AckDto() {
}
...getters/setters...
```

`PersonDto`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PersonDto extends BaseDto {

...fields...
public PersonDto() {
}
...getters/setters...
}
```

and `BaseDto`

```
public class BaseDto implements Serializable
```

Rest Api iface:

```
@POST
@Path("/ack/set")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
String setAck(AckInfoDto ackInfo);
```

RestEasy dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I run the POST req with body:

```
{
    "ackInfoDto": {

    "ackDto": {
        "consentId": "57164da116697f22fcddecc5",
        "revokeDate" : null,
        "source": "source",
        "browserInfo": "chrome",
        "ipAddress" : "IP",
        "remark" : "remark"
    },

    "personDto": {

        "firstName": "janko",
        "lastName": "hrasko",
            "email": "janko@hrasko1.com"

    }
}
}
```

The problem I have:

personDto is null on server no matter what I do.
ackDto is filled and present

I'm using WildFly9.
I have no idea what is wrong. I've tried googling a lot, removing produces.consumes xml, removing xmlroot element, but nothing worked